# I screwed up my terminal path now i can't load rvm or ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, path, rvm

I have tried and searched for days to solve this is issue. I am new to programming/coding and I somehow screwed up my path in terminal.

I was following a Ruby on Rails tutorial and it went south. My rvm is installed in the wrong place and nothing i do has fixed it. I am on High Sierra and i have `xcode9` installed.

I have tried to export `:$PATH`, I have tried `nano` editor, I have even tried to implode `rvm` (it wouldn't let me because i was outside of rvmrc).

When I `echo $PATH` I get:

```
:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Applications/.rvm/bin" before i started trying to fix it, it was ":/usr/local/opt/libiconv/bin:/Applications/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Applications/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/Applications/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Applications/.rvm/bin
```

In both cases, the rvm is at the end of the path.

Comment: which OS are you running? whenever i forget something about rvm this is my go to guide http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

Comment: sorry i missed the tags, mac, don't really know if is the same

Comment: From basic knowledge, why dont you create a soft link to the path you want it installed from the path you installed it on, i.e ln -s "currentpath" "intendedpath. That is the binary folder where the exection is, you can always move the wrong path as well after linking them.

Comment: You mean you screwed up your path in your shell init file?

Comment: I am having problems moving the path. Each time i try, it never seems to hold. I know i am a novice so i am sure it is a simple procedure, i just have not come across it yet.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not sure of the difference? I entered "source /etc/profile"  and now my path looks like :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin

Comment: hi @OlaB i have googled that suggestion but i am not sure i am comfortable trying it...but i will. I am just unsure of the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just reinstalled MAMP Pro and now my ruby/ROR works again. I still occasionally get the terminal message but it doesn't crash my program and i can just ignore it.